# How to bind a single object instance in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am a WPF newcomer, and I've been searching for two days with no luck.  I have a WPF window that has several text box controls, and a single object with some properties.  This object is passed to the codebehind of my WPF window in it's constructor:

```
public partial class SettingsDialog : Window
{
    public SettingsObject AppSettings
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public SettingsDialog(SettingsObject settings)
    {
        this.AppSettings = settings;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The `SettingsObject` looks something like this (simplified for clarity):

```
public class SettingsObject
{
    public string Setting1 { get; set; }
    public string Setting2 { get; set; }
    public string Setting3 { get; set; }

    public SettingsObject()
    {
        this.Setting1 = "ABC";
        this.Setting2 = "DEF";
        this.Setting3 = "GHI";
    }
}
```

And my WPF window (simplified):

```
<Window x:Class="MyProgram.SettingsDialog" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            DataContext="{Binding Source=AppSettings}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="Setting1Textbox" Text="{Binding Path=Setting1}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="Setting2Textbox" Text="{Binding Path=Setting2}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="Setting3Textbox" Text="{Binding Path=Setting3}"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How do you acheive two-way binding in this situation?  I've tried what you see above (and so much more) but nothing works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set the DataContext property of the window to your instance of AppSettings?

```
public SettingsDialog(SettingsObject settings)
{

    InitializeComponent();

    //While this line should work above InitializeComponent,
    // it's a good idea to put your code afterwards.
    this.AppSettings = settings;

    //This hooks up the windows data source to your object.
    this.DataContext = settings;
}
```

Comment: FYI, you were trying to bind the Window DataContext in your XAML and that is what was not working. You should remove the DataContext binding from your XAML if you're going to do the binding in the code-behind.

Comment: @Dave White - good point.  I didn't notice that in the <window> tag.