# WPF Bind to resource instance

Tags: wpf, binding, instance

I have a ContextMenu defined in XAML and I modify it in code:

```
ContextMenu EditContextMenu;
EditContextMenu  = (ContextMenu)this.FindResource("EditContextMenu");
//Modify it here...
```

Then, I need to set it as a `ContextMenu` for all TextBoxes, DatePickers, etc in a XAML theme file using data binding. I've tried adding a property to the main window :

```
    public ContextMenu sosEditContextMenu
    {
        get
        {
            return EditContextMenu;
        }
    }
```

...and binding it like this (the folowing is from a theme file with '`FTWin`' being the `Name` of my main window where the `sosEditContextMenu` property is defined):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{Binding Source=FTWin, Path=sosEditContextMenu}"/>
</Style>
```

...but it doesn't work. I've tried various things and I either got Exceptions about resources not being found or nothing happened.

Is what I'm trying to do possible and, if yes, what am I doing wrong?
I don't know if [setting the DataContext of an object could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129116/how-to-bind-a-single-object-instance-in-wpf), but setting it for all TextBoxes by code is not so nice right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the menu that you defined in xaml in a resource dictionary that can be seen from the textbox and instead of using a binding just use StaticResource to link it in your style.

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenu.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>

        <!-- The XAML defined context menu, note the x:Key -->
        <ContextMenu x:Key="EditContextMenu">
            <ContextMenu.Items>
                <MenuItem Header="test"/>
            </ContextMenu.Items>
        </ContextMenu>

        <!-- This sets the context menu on all text boxes for this window .-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource EditContextMenu}"/>
        </Style>        
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <!-- no context menu needs to be defined here, it's in the sytle.-->
        <TextBox />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can still change it in code behind by looking for the resource

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu editContextMenu = (System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu)FindResource("EditContextMenu");
    editContextMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "new item" });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used to do sth similar before, and for some peculiar reason I either got two different instances of the ContextMenu or I got a `'{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for property 'ContextMenu'` Exception. I had started thinking that `FindResource()` returns different instances sometimes. Since that's not the case, I guess there must be sth wrong with the way I merge resource dictionaries or/and with the way I change the theme.

Comment: FindResource will return a new instance if you've done something like setting x:Shared="False" on the style, any of those around (maybe try forcing it to true and see if that solves your problem). - it won't appear on intellisense but it's there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) I think I got an idea of what can be going wrong.

Comment: I was also trying to define the `ContextMenu` in a different XAML file (outside of my theme) before and perhaps this is the reason for the other problems that I've encountered (when I change the theme I need to keep one resource dictionary in my merged dictionary as is and replace the other - that seems to be problematic).

Comment: One dictionary in my merged dictionary has the ContextMenu and some general styles and the other is the theme. Right now I'm having some trouble making it work the way I want when it comes to changing the theme, but we'll see...

Comment: What do you think? Can I do it like this: with two XAML files (one for the general styles/Menu definitions and the other for the theme) or I would run into problems?

Comment: The reason that I got multiple instances was (I think) that I used to set some ContextMenus by code. Then, when I changed the theme perhaps the old ContextMenus remained. The `'{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for property 'ContextMenu'` Exception is sth that I must investigate more (I must be doing sth wrong with my merged dictionaries)...

Comment: I guess that if I use only one XAML file for the theme and the rest (Menu definitions) I will have no problems. I will just have to repeat the same stuff many times in different files (and will have a hard time maintaining them later).

Comment: _"The reason that I got multiple instances was (I think) that I used to set some ContextMenus by code."_ Note: I was also keeping an instance reference to set the ContextMenu (I didn't use `FindResource`).

Comment: Problem not solved... For some reason it seems that the ContextMenu used by my TextBoxes is not the one I get from `FindResource` (again). x:Shared="True" didn't help either. I guess I must do some digging alone to see what's going on...

Comment: OK. It seems that when I change the theme and remove and re-add the XAML file that defines the ContextMenu I get different instances of the Menu from `FindResource` (makes sense). So now I have no duplicate menus but I only get the Exception I mentioned above before I change the theme to a new one (for some reason it cannot find the ContextMenu defined in my default merged dictionary?). I don't know why is that.

Comment: I have another problem/question, if someone is interested in answering: when I create and place in the UI a new control by code it seems that the style is not applied to it. I create TextBoxes and while the style for them is not applied, the style for their scroll bars seems to get applied!!! When I define the control in XAML everything seems OK. Any idea why this happens? Should I call some function after creating the control by code to say "apply the style"?

Comment: Wow this is a long conversation thread (with yourself! haha) probably best to post another question by now I would think, these long threads aren't very helpful to other people trying to look up answers. The scope of the style should still apply even if you've added objects with code behind.

Comment: I guess you are right. Thanks! :)
I think I know what's wrong again...
I think it's because it's a derived class the one I'm using and a style will not be applied to derived types.